# Get Attributes of a Hidden Element

Tags: java, testing, selenium, webdriver

I have a table I am trying to test. Inside one of the columns is yes/no radio buttons which when the page is rendered is hidden underneath an image so that there is a check-mark or an X when yes or no is selected.

The attribute for the radio button when yes is selected `checked="true"`.

How do I with `Selenium2` get that attribute so that I can compare it or make assertions against it?

I have tried the following, which simply results in a null pointer error.

```
private void verifyPOEligibleYesNull(String driverName)
{
    int min = 1;
    int max = 6;
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    //Navigate to System Facing
    driver = browser.getDriver(driverName);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.navigate().to("http://theURL");

    //Enter userName
    WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    userName.clear();
    userName.sendKeys(user);

    //Enter Password
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("pword"));
    password.clear();
    password.sendKeys(pwd);

    //Click Login
    WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/form/div[3]/div/input"));
    loginBtn.click();
    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    WebElement ivToPoBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/ul/li/a/img"));
    ivToPoBtn.click();
    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Grab a random row and determine whether the PO Eligible is "Yes"
    String rowNum = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min);
    WebElement randomRow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum+"]/td/div/div/input")); 
    String poEligibleChecked = randomRow.getAttribute("checked").toString();
    stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\""+poEligibleChecked+"\");");
    stringBuilder.append("return x.toString();");
    String res  = (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
    System.out.println(res);    
}
```

I have even tried the following which was suggested from [WebDriver FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_Why_is_it_not_possible_to_interact_with_hidden_elements?):

```
    WebElement randomRow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum+"]/td/div/div/input")); 
    String poEligibleChecked = randomRow.getAttribute("checked");
    String element = js.executeScript("return arguments[0].getText();", poEligibleChecked).toString();
    System.out.println(element);
```

With similar null pointer exception error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't really make sense. In order to get the `checked` attribute of an invisible element, simply use [`element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute):

```
final String scriptGetChecked = "return arguments[0].getAttribute('checked')";

WebElement randomRow = driver.findElement(By.whatever("something"));
String checkedState = (String) js.executeScript(scriptGetChecked, randomRow);
```

Comment: I am still getting a `NullPointerException` when I tried what you have above. The line I am getting the exception on is the last one, where I run the `JavaScriptExecutor`